# GWT: DataGrid - set height 100% not rendering properly

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I am working with layout panels and datagrid. When I set the datagrid height to 100%, Grid is not rendering. My panel hierarchy looks like the following image

[image]

Am I doing it properly or I messed up the panel hierarchy???

Parent panel is the simple layout panel, inside that I have split layout panel -> scrollpanel -> datagrid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataGrid` requires to be put in a `LayoutPanel` or `Panel` that implements the `ProvidesResize` interface to be visible. `ScrollPanel` implements that interface.

Furthermore this chain of `LayoutPanels`  from your `DataGrid` up to your root element/panel has to be unbroken. That seems to be the case in your panel hierarchy.

Finally you have to use the `RootLayoutPanel` instead of the `RootPanel` to add your `LayoutPanels`.
So did you make sure that you add your `SimpleLayoutPanel` to the `RootLayoutPanel` ?

Comment: yes i added SimpleLayoutPanel to the RootLayoutPanel, but no success

Comment: can you check with the Developertools from Chrome or Firebug from Firefox, how the HTML structure looks like and maybe also post your Ui:binder xml structure or if you create the Panels via code the sourcecode

Comment: I got it right now... somewhere in the hierarchy I have used vertical panel. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by this:
   [DataGrid rows not visible in second tab of TabLayoutPanel](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6889)