# Can't display GWT DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

So I'm having a heck of a time creating a Datagrid with GWT. I've created my table according the the docs for GWT, and I've added my data, but I can't get it or the datagrid itself to show up at all. What am I missing? I feel I've been tearing my hair out over this. I feel like making an aysnc call might be an issue, but I get no errors. When i compile and execute this portion of my code nothing shows up on the screen and the area where the datagrid is supposed to be on the dock is empty. Am I forgetting something trivial?

```
        static int orderID = 1001;
        private static List<OrderLine> orderLineList = new ArrayList<OrderLine>();

        final DataGrid<OrderLine> dgOrder = new DataGrid<OrderLine>();
        dgOrder.setWidth("100%");                   

        //set columns
        TextColumn<OrderLine> orderLineIdColumn = new TextColumn<OrderLine>(){
            @Override
            public String getValue(OrderLine object) {
              return Integer.toString(object.getOrderLineID());
            }
        };
        dgOrder.addColumn(orderLineIdColumn, "OrderLine ID");

        TextColumn<OrderLine> productColumn = new TextColumn<OrderLine>(){
            @Override
            public String getValue(OrderLine object) {
              return getProductName(object.getProductNumber());
            }
        };
        dgOrder.addColumn(productColumn, "Product");

        TextColumn<OrderLine> quantityColumn = new TextColumn<OrderLine>(){
            @Override
            public String getValue(OrderLine object) {
              return Integer.toString(object.getQuantity());
            }
        };
        dgOrder.addColumn(quantityColumn, "Quantity");   

        // add data to datagrid
        Ioma.dataservice.getOrderLines(orderID, new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<OrderLine>>(){
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("error in retrieving GP.getOrderLines" + caught.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<OrderLine> result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               //yes i realize I could also set it to "result" but I use the result in other places as well, I have also tried setting it to result with no success
                orderLineList = result;
                dgOrder.setRowData(0, orderLineList);
            }
        });

        //add datagrid to the dock 
        dock.add(dgOrder, DockPanel.EAST);

        //add dock to mainPanel
        return dock;
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use the [`DataGrid`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html) you need to give it an explicit size. For [`CellTable`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html) you don't need to so that's why it worked.

When you were using the `DataGrid` is was there but had both height and width of `0`. So you either need to explicitly set the size:

```java
DataGrid<OrderLine> grid = new DataGrid<OrderLine>;
grid.setWidth("500px");
grid.setHeight("600px");
dock.add(dgOrder, DockPanel.EAST);
```

or you can put the gird in a [`ProvidesResize`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LayoutPanel.html) widget. So in your case I believe you can make it work with a [`DockLayoutPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html) as opposed to a [`DockPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockPanel.html) which is what you seem to be using.

Answer (score 1):

I had a smilliar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173108/gwt-datagrid-does-not-show-data-but-contains-it) . Try to put the datagrid in a Panel that implements the ProvidesResize interface, like SimpleLayoutPanel. Also in my case it helped to set the size of the SimpleLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was my declaration.

```
 final DataGrid<OrderLine> dgOrder = new DataGrid<OrderLine>();
```

should be

```
final CellTable<OrderLine> dgOrder = new CellTable<OrderLine>();
```

I can't find out why this works, but it does. I can see my table now. are you not supposed to explicitly call an instance of datagrid I wonder?

Comment: I think that CellTables and DataGrids have different methods of determining what size they should be. DataGrids are a lot more picky and don't work in some cases without workarounds. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15011854/738081

Comment: All you've done with the code above is call celltable.  Datagrid is a different (better) widget.  The likely reason it doesn't show up is that you're not using the correct containing panel (must support resize).